# EntityHistoryHelper.ShouldSavePropertyHistory throws null exception when updating record

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, aspnetboilerplate

Using MVC jQuery, .NET Core, ABP v3.5.0.

Entity History is enabled:  `Configuration.EntityHistory.IsEnabled = true;`

I inserted some data directly into a table using t-sql.
If I then try to update one of those records via the web app, I see an exception thrown:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Abp.EntityHistory.EntityHistoryHelper.ShouldSavePropertyHistory(PropertyEntry propertyEntry, Boolean defaultValue) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityHistory\EntityHistoryHelper.cs:line 292
   at Abp.EntityHistory.EntityHistoryHelper.GetPropertyChanges(EntityEntry entityEntry) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityHistory\EntityHistoryHelper.cs:line 210
   at Abp.EntityHistory.EntityHistoryHelper.CreateEntityChangeInfo(EntityEntry entityEntry) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityHistory\EntityHistoryHelper.cs:line 160
   at Abp.EntityHistory.EntityHistoryHelper.CreateEntityChangeSet(ICollection`1 entityEntries) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityHistory\EntityHistoryHelper.cs:line 95
   at Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpZeroCommonDbContext`3.<SaveChangesAsync>d__98.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

I disabled the Entity History and removed the Entity History selector and the updates are now working again for the records inserted directly into the tables using t-sql.

```
Configuration.EntityHistory.IsEnabled = false;

//Configuration.EntityHistory.Selectors.Add(
//    new NamedTypeSelector(
//        "Abp.AuditedEntity",
//        type => typeof(IAudited).IsAssignableFrom(type)
//    )
//);
```

Is the Entity History feature dependent upon the data having to be inserted via the web app?

Comment: Similar to [#3214](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3214). Can you provide a repro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the Entity History feature dependent upon the data having to be inserted via the web app?

No.

---

This has been fixed in ABP v3.6.0: [#3314](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/3314)

> *As the [documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/c8bc1783f44cae6b9c0182b734d9bfc3761e75e5/src/EFCore/Metadata/IPropertyBase.cs#L33) says `PropertyInfo` can be null for shadow properties or properties mapped directly to fields.*

Essentially, this involved a `null` check in **EntityHistoryHelper.cs**:

```cs
// if (propertyInfo.IsDefined(typeof(DisableAuditingAttribute), true))
   if (propertyInfo != null &&
       propertyInfo.IsDefined(typeof(DisableAuditingAttribute), true))
```

Comment: Yes - i have no problems now